# Calling function within prototype object

Tags: javascript

How can I call PrintIt foo from Set()? I get error that it can't find it...
I know it's possible to call it via MyObject.prototype.PrintIt but this way i will "lose" the object and it's property (Num)

```
MyObject = function(){           
    this.Num=6;            
}


MyObject.prototype = {
    initialize: function(){     
        document.getElementById("button1").onclick = this.Set;
    },
    Set: function(){
        this.PrintIt();
    },                                
    PrintIt: function(){
        alert("I Print"); 
        //alert( this.Num);                       
    }                
}

window.onload = function(){              
    obj = new MyObject;
    obj.initialize();                                
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem lies not in the prototype but in the way how you assign the method to the click handler. *There* it loses its connection to the object. You can use a closure:

```
initialize: function(){
    var that = this;     
    document.getElementById("button1").onclick = function(){
        that.Set();
    };
},
```

Comment: I always forget about closure... Is there a "rule of thumb" for that?

Comment: @shlomjmi: You mean *when* to use it? Whenever you assign a method, but want to execute the method in the object's context. But this practice will probably disappear, when `bind()` is more supported: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: Well I can't get it for 100% when I must use closure, I know for exaple that closure is used wen assigning events in a loop... (otherwise only the last index will be assigned)

Comment: @shlomjmi: If you understand *how* JavaScript works, then you will know when to use closures ;) Or whenever you are wondering why something does not work, remember closures, maybe they help :)