# Trying to remove multiple code duplication using Javascript prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

In this code:

```
MyClass.prototype = {

    methodA: function() {
        var obj = this;

        $('#my-field').keyup(function(){
            obj.methodB();
        });
    },
    methodB: function() {
        var obj = this;

        $('.flag').click(function(){
            obj.methodC($(this), $(this).attr('data-id-flag'));
            obj.methodD();
        });
    },

    ...

}
```

Is there a way to remove the below multiple declarion that exists in some methods?

```
var obj = this;
```

The reason i have to use this is explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142554/calling-function-within-prototype-object).

Comment: if there are, I think they'll be even more verbose than what you've got.

Comment: Terminology FYI: `var obj = this;` is not a closure (it's just a variable assignment). The anonymous functions you're passing to `keyup` and `click` are closures. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: +1 for @Jordan, plus `obj` is a local scope variable that the closures access. Remove any of them and you have a reference error at `obj.`.

Comment: @Jordan, Thanks to advice, i edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you mean is how can you pass the context to those closures.

You can do that using `.bind(this)` or `$.proxy(function(){}, this)`.

```
MyClass.prototype = {

    methodA: function() {

        $('#my-field').keyup($.proxy(function(){
            this.methodB();
        }, this));
    },
    methodB: function() {

        $('.flag').click($.proxy(function(e){
            var $el = $(e.currentTarget);
            this.methodC($el, $el.attr('data-id-flag'));
            this.methodD();
        }, this));
    },
}
```

[bind docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

[proxy docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/)

Comment: +1, just note that by doing this you will lose the original `this` of the event handler and you would have to use `event.target` to obtain the element.